# Use one List(Of String) in several classes for logging purposes

Tags: .net, vb.net, logging, generic-list

I am working on a VB.NET project that uses multiple classes and writes error messages and logging messages to a file using System.IO FileWriter.  I want to change this behavior and collect the error messages and logging messages in a single List(Of String) that I can send to another application.  What I'm asking for here is similar to having a global variable of type List(Of String) that I can use in several classes.  Here's an example of what I am asking for:

Dim loggingList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

Class 1:
loggingList.Add("message string")

Class 2:
loggingList.Add("message string")

Class 3:
loggingList.Add("message string")

I realize what I defined above was an instance variable of type List(Of String), but the behavior I am going for is to use the same List(Of String) in all three classes.  Not sure what I should do or how to do it.  I'm thinking that I should define a static class with the List(Of String) in it, but I am not sure.

I've been reading up on static classes, but I'm not finding the information I need to answer my question.  I want to use the same List(Of String) in separate classes, and I already have the code to send that list to another application once I have collected all the messages.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Create a module (this will be global) and declare your list there as `Dim loggingList as New List(Of String)`.

Comment: The are several really good logging libs around rather than reinvent the tool, but a class to do all this for you makes sense.  One instance could log everything for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a class with a `Shared Property` that is your list:

```
Public Class Logging
    Public Shared Property LogMessages As New List(of String)
End Class
```

The you can Add an Entry like this anywhere in your application:

```
Logging.LogMessages.Add("message string")
```

This is a better option than using a module because you can extend the functionality in the future

Comment: I went ahead and implemented the Module option before reading this last response.  Thank you for clarifying the distinction between using class and the module.  The code that passes the List(Of String) takes a list as a parameter.  How can I pass my loggingList as a parameter using it's property getter?

Comment: Simply call `MyMethod(Logging.LogMessages)`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you have a lot of options and will just need to pick an approach you feel best suites your needs, but I'll share a few examples from various products we develop.

*Static log*

As @Matt Wilko already shared, you could take one of the simpler approaches and have a static `List<String>` for logs. If you're logging requirements are really that straightforward, this might be the best approach. It gives you what you want, shared logs accessible throughout your application with the least programming required.

```
public static class Log
{
    private static readonly List<String> entries = new List<String>();
    public static ICollection<String> Entries => entries;
}
```

The only note I will add is that I would expose this as `ICollection<String>` as `List<String>` is more intended as a private implementation detail of a class, rather than a public api type, though it might be a `List<String>` internally, the caller doesn't need to know that, or care.

*Unit of work logging api*

I wrote a logging api as part of our data layer. We have a standard log viewer we built as part of our web application, but all of our software logs to the same location using a  consistent api. In our case, this is ultimately using `Entity Framework`, but it could be a `StreamWriter` or `FileStream`. You can ignore that and focus only on the api design.

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    context.Log.NewEntry(LogCategory.Information, "Message");
}
```

I also designed various options for performance because we have millions of rows, so you can do things like disable `context.AutoSave` until you're ready to write the logs out. And, while this was part of our data layer, it was abstracted into its own `LogContext`.

```
using (var logger = new LogContext())
{
    logger.NewEntry(LogCategory.Error, "Message");
}
```

And ultimately, we did implement this in another layer as a `Singleton` so the logs would be shared, so we had a single `LogContext` for the application.

*Component logging*

I recently wrote an application where I wanted to collect logging at the end of the process and display that to the user. In my case, it was a wizard based application where each page derived from the same base class and was responsible for its own logging.

```
public abstract class UpgradeStep
{
    public ICollection<Log>
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

public class DatabaseUpgradeStep : UpgradeStep
{
    public override void PerformStep()
    {
        Log.Add(new UpgradeLog { Message = "Hello" });
    }
}
```

In my case, logs were not a just a `System.String`, but at the end of the wizard process I was able to enumerate through my collection of `UpgradeSteps` and generate a collective log from the various steps.

There are a lot of ways to implement logging, and as I said, pick one that is simple and best suites your needs, unless you need something more complex. In your case, it sounds like your needs are pretty basic, but I'll leave you with a few tips we live by after writing too much logging.

- Try to separate your logging from your logic by using events, callbacks, adapters
- Put logging verbiage into a resource file so it can be modified without changing code
- Use status codes instead of lengthy verbiage where appropriate